# How to limit the number of posts that WP_Query gets?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query

I have been researching on Google and WPSE and the only thing I see repeatedly is to use `showposts`, that is deprecated.

I am familiar with `WP_Query`, and I thought that if I set `posts_per_page` to my limit (ie. 5), and `nopaging` to `true`, it would become to something like "*Ok, I'll give you only 5 posts*". But this doesn't work.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Just `'posts_per_page=5'`

Comment: I use that, but that found all the posts. If I access to the `found_posts` property, it says a higher number than 5. I want my query to hold only 5 posts. ¿Is it possible? @PieterGoosen

Comment: You should not set the `nopaging` parameter, setting that to true means to get **all** posts

Comment: @PieterGoosen If I don't set the `nopaging` parameter it gets the default that is `false`, so the frontpage shows 5 posts, but the query holds more. I add an image to the question.

Comment: Your comments are confusing, you asked to limit the amount of posts shown on a page to 5, that is what you get. Now, you say (reread your previous comment :-)) the query holds more. Please explain. You cannot set posts_per_page and then use no_paging set to true in the same query, it is either posts_per_page **OR** nopaging set to true

Comment: My question says "gets". I think that if the query holds more posts that the shown ones, it is doing more work than needed. I just want to know if it is possible to avoid that. I don't want navigable results with a hidden navigation.

Comment: The query will not hold more posts that you have asked for. If you ask for 5, 5 posts will be retrieved if there is more than 5 posts that matches the requirements. Do a `var_dump()` of your query, like if your query variable is `$query`, do `var_dump( $query->posts )`. You will only see the 5 posts you queried for

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think that now I understand what you are trying to do. When you run a custom query with `WP_Query` and set the limit to get only 5 posts per page, only 5 posts will be retrieved by the query and that query will only hold 5 posts, **BUT** for the sake of pagination, `WP_Query` still runs through the whole database and counts all the posts that matches the criteria of the query.

That can be seen when you look at the `$found_posts` and `$max_num_pages` properties of the query. Lets take an example:

You have 20 posts belonging to the default post type `post`. You **only** need the latest 5 posts without pagination. Your query looks like this

```
$q = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' );
```

- `var_dump( $q->posts )` will give you the latest 5 posts as expected
- `echo $q->found_posts` will give you `20`
- `echo $q->max_num_pages` will give you `4`

The impact of this extra work is minimal on sites with only a few posts, but this can gt expensive if you are running a site with hundreds or thousands of posts. This is a waste of resources if you are only ever going to need the 5 latest posts

There is an undocumented parameter called `no_found_rows` which uses boolean values which you can use to make your query bail after it found the 5 posts you need. This will force `WP_Query` not to look for any more posts mathing the criteria after it has retrieved the amount of posts queried. This parameter is already build into `get_posts`, that is why `get_posts` is a bit faster than `WP_Query` although `get_posts` uses `WP_Query`

## Conclusion

In conclusion, if you are not going to use pagination on a query, it is always wise to **`'no_found_rows=true'`** in your query to speed things up and to save on wasting resources.

Answer (score 9):

Ok , lets you have post type called 'blog_posts' , and you want to fetch 5 posts of that post type .   Here is what you need to do

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'blog_posts',
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
);


$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The above query will return 5 posts of type 'blog_posts' , if it is not a custom post type , then just replace like this `'post_type' => 'posts',` if you want to fetch all posts then replace like this `'posts_per_page' => '-1',` , for more details [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: See the comments on the question, please.

Answer (score 5):

I know that @user1750063 has mentioned the code but try this

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'custom_post',
    'nopaging'               => false,
    'posts_per_page'         => '5',
    'order'                  => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                => 'ID',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display content
    }
} else {
    // display when no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata();     // Restore original Post Data
```

Comment: `id` is invalid as an `orderby` value and `pagination` is an invalid parameter

Comment: `pagination`is not a valid parameter. You mean `'nopaging' => true`? If yes, then I'll get ALL posts. That's not what I want. @PieterGoosen I think he means `ID`.

Comment: orderby is for displaying the order, right? It does not harm the nopaging value/ parameter.

@PieterGoosen why is ID & orderby is invalid? Can you clarify the point?

Comment: It should be `ID`, not `id`

Answer (score 4):

After the conversation with @Pieter Goosen on the comments of the question, I think I can answer the question and explain my mistake.

The key is that `found_posts` was confussing me. I thougth that, that number is the posts retrieved but is not. **It is the number of posts that match the criteria**. It's like the `WP_Query` had 2 parts: one for finding (all) the posts, and other for fetching the content, when it checks for the `pagination` parameters. So we have the `$post_count` property that is the number of posts fetched (Codex says `The number of posts being displayed`), that of course is equal to the number on `posts_per_page` parameter, and the number of items on the `$posts` array property.

So `WP_Query` is not doing any useless work, as I thought ^^

Hope this helps others!

Comment: See my answer. I think I understand what you mean :-)

Comment: Yes! You did it very well :D Finally I got the way to do it, and I understand all =D Thanks @PieterGoosen!

Comment: Done! It extended my own answer ^^ @PieterGoosen