# Why I can't get old posts instead of recent with WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, date-query

I'm doing a `WP_Query` with a `date_query` parameter `after`, and **I want the nearest post after that date**, but I get the farest ones in the future from the date. Is there any parameter to control this? something like `'near_to' => 'past/future'`, or WP_Query always retrieve the most recent? This is my code:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d h:i',time())
    )
));
```

I have an events site, and I want to show the next one, not the farest one.

[image]

Ignore the fact that the date checked is today and the post that I search for are in the future. It doesn't matter (no?).

I have been loking at the Codex but I didn't find anything. Have I to query for ALL post and the go to the last one in the `$my_query->posts` array?

Edit: I don't want to order my results, I want to limit them by older posts, not by newest (default). I have several posts with a future date (events), and I want the next event. If I do a query with only this parameter `'posts_per_page' => 1` I get the latest post, and I want the oldest.

Thanks!

---

**The solution is to use the parameter `'order' => 'ASC'`**. Thanks to @PieterGoosen and  @webtoure. Now let me explain why my question was not 100% correct, and why it works.

I didn't test with `'order'` because I only have 1 wrong post (that was I thought), I had nothing to order, but **`WP_Query` does not works that way**. As I myself explained on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/181552/40743), `WP_Query` first finds the posts that match the criteria, and then orders them, do the pagination, etc. So you can search for posts `'after'` a date (all of them), order then by `'ASC'`, and get only 1 post with `'posts_per_page' => 1`.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are the post dates in the future, or are these dates you are talking about dates in a custom fields. File an [edit] with this required info

Comment: @PieterGoosen The dates that I'm am talking about are the `post_date`. That's why I am talking about `date_query`, and why I don't mention custom fields. I use the `No Future Posts` plugin.

Comment: You see, missing info :-). What does the plugin do, how does it change post dates and post status. Normally posts in the future have a status of `future`, so you need to change your post status parameter then

Comment: @PieterGoosen My question has nothing to do with post status. My code is working fine and give me posts, but newer instead of older. I think you guys are not understanding the question (because it's strange).

Comment: @PieterGoosen remember [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181541/how-to-limit-the-number-of-post-that-wp-query-gets)? I think we are on the shame 'problem' here. Let me do a test and then explain ^^

Comment: If you want the oldest post, then you need `'order' => 'ASC'`

Comment: I have undeleted my answer, it should do what you want :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you actually using `'after' => date('Y-m-d h:i',time())` in your code? That will always ask for posts <strike>older</strike> newer that the exact current time when that query is run. Something like this:

```
'after' => date( 'Y-m-d h:i', time() - 60 * 60 * 24 )
```

would give you a reference for 24 hours in the past.

*The above part is for history's sake. The solution in this answer **is and was** right all along though.*

As for the results being "backwords" (newest to oldest instead of vice versa) you might want to add an `order` clause to your snippet (I haven't tested it):

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => date( 'Y-m-d h:i', time() ),
        )
    ),
) );
```

**Final edit (tested and working). You need the `order` clause since WordPress queries posts 'DESC' by default. Test the code and see for yourself.**

Comment: Good answer. I would add that `date_query` accepts relatives dates. For example `'after' => '-30 days'` for last month.

Comment: I know the `order` parameter, that is not what I want to do. I have added information about it in my question. `After` gets newer posts, not older (after the date especified): [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters). `$wp_query` was only an example (bad one) and is not my real variable. @cybmeta 30 days is not always a month.

Comment: @EliasNS I have updated my response, you are using future publish posts if I understand correctly and this was **not** obvious from your question.

Comment: @webtoure I stablish a future date, but I use a plugin called `No Future Posts`, so the posts never gets the `future` status, always are `publish`. I'm going to post an image to clarify.

Comment: @EliasNS Use the `order` clause. End of story. :)

Comment: @webtoure Tested and working. Sorry and let me explain in my question :p

Comment: @EliasNS don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: @cybmeta I'm sorry but I think that the discussion solved my problem, not this concrete reply. Also, it has incorrect information about `'after'`.

Comment: @EliasNS I think you will find that my very first edit was perfectly fine and we just wasted a lot of time with you not bothering to even test the solution. ;)

Comment: @webtoure Not, **the 'after' part is wrong** (it gets posts published AFTER the date, so newer and no older), and the example is not related with the question. If you delete or fix that part I'll mark the answer. And of course, thanks for the time and the discusion, that solved my problem =D

Comment: @EliasNS Mon Dieu! That (along with the `order` clause of course) is the **exact** part that makes it work accordingly with your attached image.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Your first phrase is wrong and is not necessary. The 'order' part is right. I don't know what you say that 'after in time' means older, and not fixing it. If I buy a shirt 'after in time' that a shoes, the shirt is newer than the shoes.

Comment: @EliasNS you are confusing me; a lot. From your question and your comments, this is the answer to your problem. Even you have said that the solutin is to user the `order` parameter. But it seems that we don't understand you at all. Also, you are incorrect in the explanation of why this answer is not 100% correct. The `order` parameter is set to `DESC` by default, It doens't matter if you want to order the results or not, they are ordered already but to make WP_Query work as you want you HAVE TO CHANGE IT TO `ASC`.  That's all and that is what webtoure said to you and what solved your problem.

Comment: @cybmeta Thank you for being the one clearing this up. To my disappointment, another privileged user on this thread didn't want to make it clear that this is the final correct solution and somewhat deepened the confusion with another answer as if **this one** wasn't correct.