# How to limit WP_Query to one result on the loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, limit

I am trying to get only **one** post and this needs to be **the latest one** so here is what I am doing:

```
$basic_args = $wp_query->query_vars;
$basic_args['tax_query'] = $wp_query->tax_query;

$aditional_args = array(
    'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'order' => 'desc',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);

$normal_args = array_merge($basic_args, $aditional_args);
$normal_query = new WP_Query($normal_args);

$prev_post_ids = array();

if (!$normal_query->have_posts()) {
    $normal_args = array_merge($basic_args, array('posts_per_page' => 1));
    $normal_query = new WP_Query($normal_args);
}

echo $normal_query->post_count; // returns 25

if ($normal_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($normal_query->have_posts()) {
        ....
        // here I got 25 results instead of just one
    }
}
```

I know that `posts_per_page` should be limit how many post I will get but is not working for me and don't know why. As you can read I am getting 25 post on the loop instead of one. Can any give me some advice around this topic? I have read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181541/how-to-limit-the-number-of-posts-that-wp-query-gets) and [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) but isn't helping at all.

**Update1**

I debug the `$normal_query->request` as suggested by **@pieter-goosen** and I am getting this *wrong* SQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (6) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (6) ) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('opinion', 'post', 'especiales') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 25
```

Where the `LIMIT` is modified?

**Update2**

I have debug also the `$basic_args` which have `$wp_query->query_vars` and also `$normal_args` and here is the result:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($basic_args);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [category_name] => internacionales
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [pagename] => 
    [page_id] => 0
    [second] => 
    [minute] => 
    [hour] => 
    [day] => 0
    [monthnum] => 0
    [year] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [tag] => 
    [cat] => 409
    [tag_id] => 
    [author] => 
    [author_name] => 
    [feed] => 
    [tb] => 
    [paged] => 0
    [comments_popup] => 
    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [preview] => 
    [s] => 
    [sentence] => 
    [title] => 
    [fields] => 
    [menu_order] => 
    [category__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_name__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [cache_results] => 1
    [update_post_term_cache] => 1
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
    [post_type] => 
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [nopaging] => 
    [comments_per_page] => 50
    [no_found_rows] => 
    [order] => DESC
    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => category
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => internacionales
                                )

                            [field] => slug
                            [operator] => IN
                            [include_children] => 1
                        )

                )

            [relation] => AND
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => wp_term_relationships
                )

            [queried_terms] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => internacionales
                                )

                            [field] => slug
                        )

                )

            [primary_table] => wp_posts
            [primary_id_column] => ID
        )

)


echo '<pre>';
print_r($normal_args);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [category_name] => internacionales
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] => 
    [subpost] => 
    [subpost_id] => 
    [attachment] => 
    [attachment_id] => 0
    [name] => 
    [static] => 
    [pagename] => 
    [page_id] => 0
    [second] => 
    [minute] => 
    [hour] => 
    [day] => 0
    [monthnum] => 0
    [year] => 0
    [w] => 0
    [tag] => 
    [cat] => 409
    [tag_id] => 
    [author] => 
    [author_name] => 
    [feed] => 
    [tb] => 
    [paged] => 0
    [comments_popup] => 
    [meta_key] => 
    [meta_value] => 
    [preview] => 
    [s] => 
    [sentence] => 
    [title] => 
    [fields] => 
    [menu_order] => 
    [category__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [category__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_name__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [tag_slug__and] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [post_parent__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__in] => Array
        (
        )

    [author__not_in] => Array
        (
        )

    [ignore_sticky_posts] => 1
    [suppress_filters] => 
    [cache_results] => 1
    [update_post_term_cache] => 1
    [update_post_meta_cache] => 1
    [post_type] => 
    [posts_per_page] => 1
    [nopaging] => 
    [comments_per_page] => 50
    [no_found_rows] => 
    [order] => desc
    [tax_query] => WP_Tax_Query Object
        (
            [queries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => category
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => internacionales
                                )

                            [field] => slug
                            [operator] => IN
                            [include_children] => 1
                        )

                )

            [relation] => AND
            [table_aliases:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => wp_term_relationships
                )

            [queried_terms] => Array
                (
                    [category] => Array
                        (
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => internacionales
                                )

                            [field] => slug
                        )

                )

            [primary_table] => wp_posts
            [primary_id_column] => ID
        )

    [post_status] => publish
)
```

As you can see `post_per_page` is set to `1` here so why it's taking those 25?

**Update 3**

Apparently this is the problematic code at `functions.php`:

```
function change_wp_search_size($query)
{
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 25;
    } // Change 25 to the number of posts you would like to show
    return $query; // Return our modified query variables
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size');
```

Shouldn't this works for search only? Why is acting over all query_vars all the time?

Comment: Couple of things to check: what is the value of `$normal_args['posts_per_page']` prior to your first creation of WP_Query, and how many posts get returned from just a simple WP_Query (without the array_merges you have going on)?

Comment: @morganestes `echo 'posts_per_page: ', $normal_args['posts_per_page'];` returns `1`; `$normal_query = new WP_Query($basic_args); echo 'post_count: ', $normal_query->post_count;` returns `25`

Comment: @ReynierPM: Please check my answer, this will may help you

Comment: I get the feeling that you have a bad filter somewhere. If `$normal_args['posts_per_page']` returns `1`, but you get 25 posts back, then the value of `posts_per_page` is altered inside the `WP_Query` class. I would start by looking at `pre_get_posts` that is badly formulated.  You should look at the generated SQL query, simply do `echo $normal_query->request`. This should give you an idea if `posts_per_page` is altered right before the SQL query is build

Comment: @PieterGoosen you're right, can you take a look to the OP? I don't know where this value is modified and/or why

Comment: Make double sure `$normal_args` is what you expect it to be before chasing a wild goose. If you are sure that all values are what you expect it to be, look for any instance of `pre_get_posts` and `post_limits` in your theme and plugins. These are the popular hooks used to alter the query vars and generated SQL, and sadly, these are also the hooks which many use incorrectly which leads to the issues you are experiencing. A quick check for any interference from a `posts_*` filter is to add `'suppress_filters'=>true,`, if your query is correct afterwards, you know what to look for

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have added `'suppress_filters'=>true` and no changes still getting 25 on the query and I don't have such plugin installed.

Comment: OK, so now the only thing you need to look for is `pre_get_posts` in your theme and all plugins.

Comment: @PieterGoosen see my update3 at OP, I found the problematic code I just don't know why that behavior

Comment: `pre_get_posts` alters all queries, back end and front end regardless. There are two very important checks that a large amount of people misses, that is the `!is_admin()` check to only target the front end, and then the most important check `is_main_query()` to only alter the main query and not custom queries. So you statement should be `if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` alters all queries, back end and front end regardless.

There are two very important checks that a large amount of people misses, that is the `!is_admin()` check which only targets the front end, and then the most important check, `is_main_query()` which will only alter the main query and not custom queries.

You statement should look something like the follwoing

```
if (    !is_admin() 
     && $query->is_main_query()  
     && $query->is_search()  
) {
    // Your arguments to set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after the suggestions from **@pieter-goosen** I have found a solution, just adding this `remove_all_filters( 'pre_get_posts' )` before run that `WP_Query` fix the issue, hope it helps to others

Comment: You should correct the issue as in my last comment

Comment: Great post this as an answer and I will accept since this seems to be a better way than mine, thanks