# Limit WP_Query to only X results (total, not per page)

Tags: wp-query

How to limit WP_Query to grab only let’s say 5 results? What I mean is actually only 5 results rather than 5 posts per page.

This

> [How to limit the number of posts that WP_Query gets?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181541/how-to-limit-the-number-of-posts-that-wp-query-gets)

provides some insight and advices to use `no_found_rows=true` but do you use it with posts_per_page or do you need to limit results somewhere else?

In my case (search) `get_posts` doesn’t work as I need to provide a search query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already mentioned, to limit the number of posts retrieved by the query, you can use `posts_per_page`.

This argument works both for [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), for example:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,

);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

And as stated in the link you provided, `no_found_rows = true` will end the query after it reached its criteria. It's totally optional, and not very common.

Comment: Any idea of performance gains with `no_found_rows = true`? Is it worth it?

Comment: Worth it against how many posts? How complex queries?

Comment: Queries are search queries and category / author queries. Posts... it depends. If I rephrase my comment as “how complex should be a query and how many posts you should have to gain from limiting that way”?

Comment: A query that contains `tax_query` can be heavy. At that point, yes it might be worth it. But querying the last 10 posts or so? No, not noticeable.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for isn't a parameter of WP_Query, it is the filter `post_limits`.

> This filter applies to a query's LIMIT clause before the query is sent to the database, allowing you to define a new query LIMIT.

You can find more details here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits

Depending on your specific case, you have two ways to solve it:

1. Use a condition inside the function, like the example in the codex.
2. Don't use any condition, just return `LIMIT 0, 5`. So add the filter right before your query and remove it right after.

**UPDATE:** Added a complete example for the second solution.

Declare the functions in functions.php

```
function custom_get_posts_limit(){
    return 'LIMIT 0, 5';
}
```

Then use it wherever you want

```
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'custom_get_posts_limit' );

// Add all your others args
get_posts( array( 'suppress_filters' => false) );

remove_filter( 'post_limits', 'custom_get_posts_limit' );
```

Comment: This will only work for main query. It’s valuable addition though, thanks.

Comment: @Runnick that's not correct, you can apply the second solution wherever you want, also with the function `get_posts()`. You just need to set the parameter `suppress_filters` to false. I am going to add a complete example to the reply right now.

Comment: but you can have only one filter/limit per all queries?